# Convert Numeric String to Readable Date Format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

Let's say I have a string 2021-08-13 and want to convert this to August 13, 2021. How would you achieve this as it's not a date object.

In my mind I can think of setting each numeric month to a text version of that month and re-arrange, however seeing if there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: By turning it into a Date object and then using `DateTimeFormat` [with options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat#using_options).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: convert the string into a Date object and use the `toLocaleString` function.

If you want to get rid of the timezone so the date stays the same wherever the user is you can first convert it into an ISO string, get rid of the 'Z' in the end, and then convert it back into the Date object.

```js
const dateString = '2021-08-13'
const localeOptions = {dateStyle: 'long'}

const dateTimezone = new Date(dateString).toLocaleString('en-US', localeOptions)
const dateWithoutTimezone = new Date(new Date(dateString).toISOString().slice(0,-1)).toLocaleString('en-US', localeOptions)

console.log(dateTimezone)
console.log(dateWithoutTimezone)
```

Comment: '2021-08-13' is parsed as UTC so will not produce the expected date in places west of Greenwich, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Yes, and that's precisely why I mentioned how to remove the timezone. Didn't understand your point.

Comment: There is no explanation of why the first example fails, nor why "*If you want to get rid of the timezone…*" is necessary when there isn't one. The inefficiency of `string -> Date -> string -> string -> Date -> string` vs `string -> Date -> string` or `string -> string` should be clear.

Answer (score -1):

Convert your string date to a JS Date Object

```js
let strDate = "2021-08-13";
let date = new Date(strDate);

console.log(date.toDateString())
```

Learn more about Date object here: [JavaScript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)